Is there any way to make a fetch request to a server with a self-signed certificate at the edge?
In runtime=nodejs (at vercel) I can do
import { Agent } from 'undici'

await fetch(url, {
    dispatcher: new Agent({
        connect: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
    }),
})

But how do I make the same request on the runtime=edge?
I can't use undici on the edge because there is no node:dependencies.
Same with NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED - no effect.
